# Merging 2 data frames with different sizes

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames that I would like to merge. In `df1`observation were recorded on 2 different days. Each record has an index , id1  person  identification number and id2 refers the number of the day that recording was made (day had to be different ).There is also a Day variable that records the week day when the recording was made.

In `df2` observations were recorded just based on serial number and id1 person identification number. There is just one observation per person. Similarly here there is also a Day variable that records when the recordings were made.

I would like to identify the observations from df2 that were recorded on the same day as in df1.

How can I do this?

Sample data

df1:

```
    structure(list(index = c(11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011203, 11011203, 11011207, 11011207, 11011207, 11011207, 11011209, 
11011209, 11011209, 11011209, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 11011210, 
11011211, 11011211, 11011211, 11011211, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 
11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011213, 11011213, 
11011213, 11011213, 11011213, 11011213, 11011217, 11011217, 11011219, 
11011219, 11011220, 11011220, 11011220, 11011220, 11011220, 11011220, 
11020202, 11020202, 11020202, 11020202), id1 = c(1, 1, 4, 4, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
1, 1, 2, 2), id2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Day = c(5, 1, 5, 
1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 7, 5, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 7, 2, 
7, 2, 7, 2, 7, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4, 7, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 4, 7, 4, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df2:

```
    structure(list(Day = c(3, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 6, 
6, 6, 4, 3, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6), index = c(11011209, 11011209, 
11011210, 11011212, 11011212, 11011213, 11011213, 11011220, 11011220, 
11020208, 11020212, 11020212, 11020301, 11020301, 11020301, 11020305, 
11020310, 11020315, 11020315, 11020316, 11020316, 11020320, 11020606, 
11020611, 11020611), id1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi there, all of your "outcome" is wholly present in `df1`. Is this a merging question or a subset question? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Ian Campbell I tried to merge the 2 data frames. I want to identify the observations from df2 that are recorded in df1. The difference between the observation is that in df1  with the same index and id1 2 different observations were made but on different date. Many thanks

Comment: I edited my answer based on your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the datasets have `duplicate` `by` variables, resulting in duplication of rows after the `join`. One option is to `nest` by those variables, and then do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
      group_by(Day, index) %>%
      nest %>%
      left_join(df1 %>% 
                   rename(idnew = id1)) %>% 
      unnest(data)
```

Comment: many thanks I updated my data sample - basically I would like to merge df2 (25 observation) with df1 (50 observation) aiming for 25 observations. But I don't know why after merging I receive 50 obs.

Comment: @user11964604 i checked your `dput`, you have both datasets have duplicates for 'Day', 'index', resulting in duplication after the merge Check `count(df2, Day, index)` and `count(df1, Day, index)`

Comment: @user11964604 i updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: i receive an error suggesting  Error in rename(., idnew = id1) : unused argument (idnew = id1)
>

Comment: @user11964604 it could be that `rename` is masked from other package function of the same name.  can you chhange it to `dplyr::rename(idnew = id1))`

Comment: @user11964604 iff you can update with an expected output, it would be easier to crosscheck

Comment: apologise and many thanks for your continuous help I am literally stuck on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187493/identify-consecutive-sequences-based-on-a-given-variable question - I was thinking to aggregate the data on day level, but still I don't know how to set a criteria for a sequence to start with a specific day. If you have time could you please help me. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Based on your clarifications, I think this is what you wanted. I switched to using tidyverse since your data is stored in tibbles.

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1,df2,by=c("id1","Day"),suffix=c(".df1",".df2"))
#   index.df1   id1   id2   Day index.df2
#       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  11011202     1     1     5  11020316
# 2  11011202     1     1     5  11020606
# 3  11011203     1     2     3  11011209
# 4  11011203     1     2     3  11020310
# 5  11011207     1     1     4  11020212
# 6  11011207     1     1     4  11020305
# 7  11011207     1     2     7  11011220
# 8  11011207     1     2     7  11020315
# 9  11011207     2     1     4  11011210
#10  11011207     2     1     4  11020212
## … with 43 more rows
```

Comment: i tried this it reduces the number of observations. For example in my case df1 has 2942 observations and df2 16533 observations. After merging I receive 169 observations and not 2942. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @user11964604 If that's not what you want, I would say the mistake is in your question. Your question shows `df1` with 6 rows, `df2` with 2 rows, and an output with 2 rows. This answer produces an output with 2 rows, just like your question asks for...  if that's not what you want, please edit your question to make it clearer what you do want.

Comment: Hi My suggestion : (1).You can Check your Day column like remove extra space by ```gsub()``` or letter small or capital. (2). convert the day column in character (3). convert Index column to numeric ... then try it  ```merge()``` with ```all.x=T```

Comment: @Ian Campbell many thanks I updated the sample data with df1 (50obs) and df2 (25obs). I would like to have 25 (obs) but it gives me 50.

Comment: @GregorThomas I updated the sample data: basically I would like to have a df3 with 25 observation but I don't know how to merge the data frames.

Comment: @Ian Campbell if you have time I updated my question

Comment: @GregorThomas if you have time I updated my question